# Subversive: how to manage a conflict on the svn:mergeinfo property?

Tags: subversive, svn-merge, svn-merge-reintegrate

I'm trying to make a merge operation with **Subversive** in **Eclipse**.

I've been able to manage all the conflicts on the files structure, but it remains a conflict on the `svn:mergeinfo` property.

I've tried everything, but I'm not able to solve this conflict:

[image]

The plugin has a `Mark as merged` option, but it doesn't happen anything choosing that option.

I have also tried to remove the property, or to modify its own value, but nothing happens in any case, and the conflict is still present.

If I try an `Override and commit`, the status of the Folder of the project is `Conflicting`, also visible in the `SVN Info` on the properties of the project.

It seems that Subversive can't manage a conflict on this property: is that possible?

How can I solve this conflict?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I haven't found yet a solution directly with Subversive, I hacked the issue using a tool like SmartSVN.

With that tool I had been able to mark the conflict as solved, so I can say that it's a bug (or maybe a missing feature) of the current version of Subversive.